# Disable SSMS Job on linked server based on previous job status

Tags: sql-server, jobs, linked-server, job-scheduling

I have multiple jobs that kick off at various times in the AM to load our DW.  However if one of those jobs fail, I want to disable all my other morning jobs as they are dependent on one another.  However the jobs I want to disable are on a linked server.

I have multiple jobs that kick off at various times in the AM to load our DW.  However if one of those jobs fail, I want to disable all my other morning jobs as they are dependent on one another.  However the jobs I want to disable are on a linked server.

I have modified the job and created a step to disable specific jobs in the event the previous Step fails.  During this step I am disabling multiple jobs that span across 2 servers.  The job only disables the job on the current server and throws an error message
Message
Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_update_job_for_non_admins', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229).  The step failed.

I have tired manually running the job as well as running it on a schedule and still get the same results. 
All the jobs on each server are owned by the SQLServerAgent and have the same rights across both servers.

```
EXEC CYP_ABC.msdb.dbo.sp_update_job_for_non_admins
        @job_name='Earned_Premium',@enabled = 0
EXEC CYP_X.msdb.dbo.sp_update_job_for_non_admins
        @job_name='CYP_DB2_Load_BLAH',@enabled = 0
EXEC CYP_X.msdb.dbo.sp_update_job_for_non_admins
        @job_name='CYP_DB2_Update_BLAH',@enabled = 0
```

My job is run on the CYP_ABC Server and it will only disable the job on the CYP_ABC server.  I need the script to also disable the jobs on the linked server but it keeps throwing the error message listed above.

Comment: how do you connect to other servers sql server agent?

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission issue. "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" is a local account. For cross-server/instance operation a domain service account is usually assigned to the sql agent service account.

A possible workaround is to add a job step in CYP_X server jobs to query the job status on the CYP_ABC server.

Answer (score 0):

The job will need to be executed by a login that has a user in the `msdb` database with permission to execute that stored procedure.  You could create a user for the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM login, but I'd suggest creating a user for a login other than this account.  Then you can use the login this user was created from to run this job.  If you do this, make sure that the login has the proper permissions to perform all of the other actions within the job.  An example of creating a user and granting this user permissions on the `sp_update_job_for_non_admins` stored procedure is below.  Also make sure that the user has the permissions on the objects used by this stored procedure, although from the title of the SP I'm guessing that it's intended to be used by users with lesser permissions and executes as who created it.

```
USE [msdb]

GO

Create USER [UserInMSDB] FOR LOGIN [YourLoginName]

GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.sp_update_job_for_non_admins TO [UserInMSDB]
```